# Socket.io and Angular.js chat script TimeOut

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I am trying to get my chat script to work I have moved to a VPS thinking that should solve any missing extensions but I have the same problem.

A user logs into the website and can then load the chat to talk with other members - I am using the datingframework

in the console window I can see the message but socket.io keeps timing out I have tried using different ports and changing from https - http but get the same error

On their demo website when I send a chat I notice a different scroll event getting triggered before the message is displayed.

This is some of the chat js code as there is a limit on the amount I can post!!

```js
/* this is main chat controller */

App.controller('WebsocketChatController',function($scope,$rootScope,$http, socket, $timeout,$location,$anchorScroll,Upload,$log,$timeout,screenSize) {
 
 
 
    $scope.getSocketObj= function()
    {
     
     return socket;
    } 
    
    
 

    /* socket operations */

    $scope.socket_id = 0;
    socket.on('connected', function(data){
        $scope.socket_id = data.socket_id;
        $scope.mapUserWithSocket();
    });


    //if not in chatUsers array take from ajax call

    socket.on("new_message_received", function(data){


  //$scope.getChatUsers();
  
      var text = parseInt($(".notification-message").html());
   
   
 
   if(isNaN(text)){
    text= 0;
   }
   
   $(".notification-message").html(text+1); 
   
   
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  
        toastr.success(recieved_msg); 
  
        var user = $scope.findUserByID(data.from_user);
        
        
        
        //toastr.success('You got a new message from '+user.user.name);
        
        
                         
        if(data.to_user==$scope.authUser)
        {
            data.recipient='other';
        }
        else
        {
            data.recipient='self';
        }
           
           
           
            
          

        
        user.user.messages.push(data);
        
        
        

        if (user.user.last_msg == "" && user.user.id == $scope.chatUsers[$scope.selected].user.id) {
            $('#third_img_div').show();
            $('#first_img_div').hide();
            $("#no-users-div").hide();
            $("#fourth_div").hide();
        }


        if (data.type == 2) {
            user.user.last_msg = data.meta;
            user.user.last_msg_type = 2;
        } else if (data.type == 0) {
            user.user.last_msg = data.text;
            user.user.last_msg_type = 0;
        }

  
        user.user.total_messages_count += 1;
        
        
        var curr_user_id= "user-"+user.user.id;
        
        
        //if user selected and user msg recieved are differed=nt then increment otherwise no
        if(curr_user_id != $(".all_users").parent().find('.active').data('id'))
        {
         user.user.total_unread_messages_count += 1;
        
   $scope.overall_unread_messages_count += 1;
   
  } 
        var audio = new Audio("@plugin_asset('WebsocketChatPlugin/audio/ping.mp3')");
        audio.play();


        //$("#chat-container").scrollTop($("#chat-container").find("> .img_main_div_padding").height());

    });


    socket.on("new_message_sent", function(data){

        var user = $scope.findUserByID(data.to_user);
        
        
        
         
         if(data.to_user==$scope.authUser)
         {
             data.recipient='other';
         }
         else
         {
             data.recipient='self';
         }
         user.user.messages.push(data);
 
 
         if (user.user.last_msg == "" && user.user.id == $scope.chatUsers[$scope.selected].user.id) {
             $('#third_img_div').show();
             $('#first_img_div').hide();
             $("#no-users-div").hide();
             $("#fourth_div").hide();
         }
 
 
         if (data.type == 2) {
             user.user.last_msg = data.meta;
             user.user.last_msg_type = 2;
         } else if (data.type == 0) {
             user.user.last_msg = data.text;
             user.user.last_msg_type = 0;
         }

    
                        
        


        // user.user.total_messages_count += 1;
        // user.user.total_unread_messages_count += 1;
        
        //$("#chat-container").scrollTop($("#chat-container").find("> .img_main_div_padding").height());
    });

    /*end of socket operations */




    /* user online offline status */
    socket.on('user_online', function(data){

        var user = $scope.findUserByID(data.user_id);
        if (user) {
            user.online = 1;
        }

    });

    socket.on('user_offline', function(data){

        var user = $scope.findUserByID(data.user_id);
        if (user) {
            user.online = 0;
        }

    });
    /* end user online offline status */




 //event listening to contact delete
 socket.on('contact_deleted', function(data){
  
  

       $scope.getChatUsers();

    });
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
$scope.isTypingUser=0;


    /* typing stop and start notification */

    socket.on('typing', function(data){
        var user = $scope.findUserByID(data.from_user);
        if (user) {
            user.user.isTyping = true;
            console.log(user.user.name + " is typing..");
           
      
      //$scope.isTypingUser=1;
      
      $('#typing_'+user.user.id).show();

        }
        
    });

    socket.on('typing_stop', function(data){
        var user = $scope.findUserByID(data.from_user);
        if (user) {
            user.user.isTyping = false;
            console.log(user.user.name + " is stopped typing..");
            
            
            $('#typing_'+user.user.id).hide();
           
        }
    });


    $scope.typing = function(){


        if (!$scope.type) {
            $scope.type = true;
            socket.emit('typing', {from_user: auth_user_id_chat, to_user:$scope.chatUsers[$scope.selected].user.id });
        }
        
        lastTypingTime = (new Date()).getTime();

        setTimeout(function () {

            var typingTimer = (new Date()).getTime();
            var timeDiff    = typingTimer - lastTypingTime;
            
            if (timeDiff >= 2000 && $scope.type) {
                socket.emit('typing_stop', {from_user: auth_user_id_chat, to_user:$scope.chatUsers[$scope.selected].user.id });
                $scope.type = false;
            }

        }, 2000);
    
    }
    /* end typing stop and start notification */







    /* new user contacted */

    socket.on("new_user_contacted", function(data){

        
        var user = $scope.findUserByID(data.user_id);

        /* if user is already in list then remove*/
        if (user) {
         if(!$scope.total_contacts_count)
         {
          $scope.chatUsers=[];
         }
         else
         {
             var index = $scope.chatUsers.indexOf(user);
             $scope.chatUsers.splice(index, 1);
            }
        } 

        //push object again retriving ajax call
        $http.post(chat_user, {user_id:data.user_id})
        .then(function(response){

            if (response.data.status == 'success') {

                //$scope.chatUsers.push(response.data.chat_user);
                var temp = [];
                temp.push(response.data.chat_user);
                $scope.chatUsers = $.merge(temp, $scope.chatUsers);
                
                $scope.chatUsers = _.uniq($scope.chatUsers, function(a) { return a.contact_id; });
                
                
                
                
    }


        }
        ,function(response){});

    });


    /* end new user contacted */












    $scope.findUserByID = function(user_id){

        if ($scope.chatUsers.length < 1)
            return null;

        return $scope.chatUsers.find(function(item){
            if(item.user.id == user_id) return true;
        });
    }



    $scope.mapUserWithSocket = function() {
        $http.post(map_user_socket, 
        {socket_id:$scope.socket_id}).then(function(response){
            
            if (response.data.status == 'success') {
                socket.emit('user_socket_mapped', {user_id:auth_user_id_chat})
                console.log('you are connected');
            }

        }, function(){});
    }
    
    
    
 
 function swapElement(array, indexA, indexB) {
   var tmp = array[indexA];
   array[indexA] = array[indexB];
   array[indexB] = tmp;
   
   return array;
 }
          

    $scope.chatUsers = [];
    $scope.chat_users_count = 0;
    $scope.total_contacts_count = 0;
    $scope.last_contact_id = 0;
    $scope.authUser = auth_user_id_chat;
    $scope.overall_unread_messages_count = 0;

    /* this method gets chat users */
    $scope.getChatUsers = function(){

        $http.get(
            
           chat_users, 
            {last_contact_id:$scope.last_contact_id}
        
        ).then(function(res){

            if(res.data.status == "success") {

                $scope.total_contacts_count = res.data.total_contacts_count;
                $scope.chatUsers = res.data.chat_users;
                
                
                if($scope.contact_id_already_contacted)
                {
                 _.each($scope.chatUsers, function(listItem,index){
                  
                  if(listItem.contact_id == $scope.contact_id_already_contacted)
                   $scope.indexToBeSelected = index;
                  
                 })
                
     $scope.chatUsers = swapElement($scope.chatUsers, $scope.indexToBeSelected,0);
    }
                
                
                $scope.chat_users_count = $scope.chatUsers.length;

                if ($scope.total_contacts_count == 0 || $scope.chat_users_count == 0) {
                    $scope.last_contact_id = 0;
                } else {
                    $scope.last_contact_id = $scope.chatUsers[$scope.chat_users_count-1].contact_id;
                }
    
                if ($scope.total_contacts_count != 0 && $scope.load_chat_data_first == true) {
                    $scope.loadChatDataFirst();
                    $('#fourth_div').hide();
                    
                }
                else
                {
                 
                 $('#fourth_div').show();
                 $('#third_img_div').hide();
              $('#first_img_div').hide();
              $("#no-users-div").hide();
                }

                $scope.overall_unread_messages_count = res.data.overall_unread_messages_count;

            }


        }, function(res){});

    }


    /* this method retrives message of a particular user */
    $scope.getMessages = function(user){

        $http.post(
            msgs_chat,
            {user_id:user.user.id, last_message_id:$scope.last_message_id}
        ).then(function(res){

            if (res.data.status == 'success') {
                var temp = [];
                $.merge(temp, res.data.messages);
                
                _.each(temp,function(item,index){
                 
                 if(item.to_user==$scope.authUser)
                 {
                  temp[index].recipient='other';
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  temp[index].recipient='self';
                 }
                 
                })
                
                user.user.messages = $.merge(temp, user.user.messages);

            }

        }, function(res){});

    }



    /* this method is used to send message */
    $scope.submitMessage = function(){
     
     console.log('$scope.messageInput',$scope.messageInput);

        var to_send_user = $scope.chatUsers[$scope.selected];
        
        if($scope.messageInput.indexOf(':')==0)
          $scope.messageInput = emojione.shortnameToUnicode($scope.messageInput)

        var msg_obj = {
            from_user : auth_user_id_chat,
            to_user : to_send_user.user.id,
            contact_id : to_send_user.contact_id,
            message_type : 0,
            message_text : $scope.messageInput
        };
        
        
        if(to_send_user.user.can_init_chat)
        {
    socket.emit('new_message', msg_obj);
  }
  else{
   
   
         
         if(to_send_user.user.init_chat_error_type === 'CHAT_INIT_HOURS_EXPIRED')
         {
           
          $('#myModalExceedsChatHourExpired').modal('show');
         }
         else if(to_send_user.user.init_chat_error_type === 'CHAT_LIMIT_OF_DAY')
         {
          $('#myModalExceedsChatLimit').modal('show');
         }
         
   Plugin.fire('chat_init_send_gift', [to_send_user]);
        
  }  
        
        $scope.messageInput='';
        
       
    }
    
    
    
    /* submit messege with media
     /* this method is used to send message */
    $scope.submitMessageWithMedia = function(image_name){

        var to_send_user = $scope.chatUsers[$scope.selected];
        
        

        var msg_obj = {
            from_user : auth_user_id_chat,
            to_user : to_send_user.user.id,
            contact_id : to_send_user.contact_id,
            message_type : 2,
            message_text : image_name
        };

   if(to_send_user.user.can_init_chat)
        {
    socket.emit('new_message', msg_obj);
  }
  else{
   
   
         
         if(to_send_user.user.init_chat_error_type === 'CHAT_INIT_HOURS_EXPIRED')
         {
                   
          $('#myModalExceedsChatHourExpired').modal('show');
         }
         else if(to_send_user.user.init_chat_error_type === 'CHAT_LIMIT_OF_DAY')
         {
          $('#myModalExceedsChatLimit').modal('show');
         }
         
   Plugin.fire('chat_init_send_gift', [to_send_user]);
        
  } 
        
       
        
       
    }


    $scope.submitMessageFirstTime = function(){

        var to_send_user = $scope.chatUsers[$scope.selected];
        
        
        if($scope.messageInput.indexOf(':')==0)
          $scope.messageInput = emojione.shortnameToUnicode($scope.messageInput)

        var msg_obj = {
            from_user : auth_user_id_chat,
            to_user : to_send_user.user.id,
            contact_id : to_send_user.contact_id,
            message_type : 0,
            message_text : $scope.messageInput
        };

  if(to_send_user.user.can_init_chat)
        {
    socket.emit('new_message', msg_obj);
    
       $scope.loadChatData(to_send_user, $scope.selected);
  }
  else{
   
   
         
         if(to_send_user.user.init_chat_error_type === 'CHAT_INIT_HOURS_EXPIRED')
         {
                    

          $('#myModalExceedsChatHourExpired').modal('show');
         }
         else if(to_send_user.user.init_chat_error_type === 'CHAT_LIMIT_OF_DAY')
         {
          $('#myModalExceedsChatLimit').modal('show');
         }
         
         
        
         Plugin.fire('chat_init_send_gift', [to_send_user]);
      
        
  } 

     
        
        $scope.messageInput='';

    }
    
    
    
    




    $scope.loadOnline =function() {
     
     var counter=0;
        $scope.onlineSelectedUsers = _.filter($scope.chatUsers, function (item,index) { 
         
         
         if(item.online && counter==0){
          
          
          $scope.chatUsers[index].user.already_clicked= 0;
          $scope.loadChatData($scope.chatUsers[index],index);
          
          counter++;
          
         }
         
         
         
         return  item.online; 
         
         
         });
         


    var onlineUsers_count = $scope.onlineSelectedUsers.length;
    
    
    if(onlineUsers_count == 0)
    {
     $('#third_img_div').hide();
              $('#first_img_div').hide();
              $("#no-users-div").show();
     

    }
    
    
    }


  $scope.loadOnline_mobile =function() {
        $scope.onlineSelectedUsers = _.filter($scope.chatUsers, function (item) { return  item.online; });
        
        if($scope.total_contacts_count)
         {
        if ($scope.onlineSelectedUsers.length == 0) {
            $('#third_img_div').hide();
            $('#first_img_div').hide();
            $("#no-users-div").show();
            return false;
        }
        
        $scope.loadChatData($scope.onlineSelectedUsers[0],0);
        }
    }


    $scope.loadMatched = function() {
     
        
              var counter=0;
       $scope.matchedUsers = _.filter($scope.chatUsers, function (item,index) { 
           
           
           if(item.matched && counter==0){
            
            
            $scope.chatUsers[index].user.already_clicked= 0;
            $scope.loadChatData($scope.chatUsers[index],index);
            
            counter++;
            
           }
           
           
           
           return  item.matched; 
          
          
          });
         


    var matchedUsers_count = $scope.matchedUsers.length;
    
    
    if(matchedUsers_count == 0)
    {
     $('#third_img_div').hide();
              $('#first_img_div').hide();
              $("#no-users-div").show();
     

    }
        
    }


    $scope.loadAll =function() {
         if($scope.total_contacts_count)
         {
        if ($scope.chatUsers.length == 0) {
            $('#third_img_div').hide();
            $('#first_img_div').hide();
            $("#no-users-div").show();
            
            return false;
        }
        
        
       
         $scope.loadChatData($scope.chatUsers[0],0);
        }
    }
    
    $scope.loadAll_mobile =function() {
        if ($scope.chatUsers.length == 0) {
         
         
            $('#third_img_div').hide();
            $('#first_img_div').hide();
            $("#no-users-div").show();
            return false;
        }
        
        if($scope.total_contacts_count)
         $scope.loadChatData($scope.chatUsers[0],0);
    }
    
    

    
    $scope.selected = 0;
    $scope.loadChatData = function(user,index) {  
     
     //$scope.selected = index; 
     
      //index = $scope.chatUsers.indexOf(user);
      
 if(user !=undefined)
 {
      $scope.current_to_user_id=user.user.id;
    
      if(!$scope.total_contacts_count)
         {
          $http.post(add_to_contacts, {user_id:user.user.id})
         .then(function(response){
 
             if (response.data.status == 'success') {
 
               $scope.getChatUsers();  
 
             }
 
 
         }
         ,function(response){});
          
      }
     //hide the button
  $('#load_more').show();

        $scope.userChatDetail = user;
        
        $scope.selected = index;
        

        if (user.user.last_msg) {
   
            $scope.last_message_id = 0;
            if (user.user.messages.length > 0) {
                $scope.last_message_id = user.user.messages[0].id;
            }

            if(!user.already_clicked) {
             $('.loaderChatData').fadeIn();
                $scope.getMessages(user);    
                user.already_clicked = 1;
                
                
                //clear unread mesg count
                user.user.total_unread_messages_count= 0;
                
                
                //call function to make unread status for this user once i click on unread mesges
                //pending
                 $http.post(
              mark_read ,
              {user_id:user.user.id}
           ).then(function(res){
  
                                
                  console.log(res);
                  
                   $('.loaderChatData').fadeOut();
  
           });
  
          
                
                
            }
            
            
            if(user.already_clicked)
            {  
             //clear unread mesg count
                user.user.total_unread_messages_count= 0;
                
                //$scope.getMessages(user);
             
            }
            

            // $scope.last_msg = user.user.last_msg;
            // $scope.last_msg_type = user.user.last_msg_type;
   
             $('#third_img_div').show();
    $('#first_img_div').hide();
    $("#no-users-div").hide();
    $("#fourth_div").hide();
    
    if($scope.mobile)
    {
     $('.mobile_users').hide();
    }
    
        }
        else
        {
   
             $('#third_img_div').hide();
             $('#first_img_div').show();
             $("#no-users-div").hide();
             $("#fourth_div").hide();
             
             if($scope.mobile)
    {
     $('.mobile_users').hide();
    }

    
        }
        
        
      }  
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    $scope.loadMoreChatData =function(user,index,last_msg_id)
    {
     $scope.userChatDetail = user;
        $scope.selected = index; 

        if (user.user.last_msg) {

            $scope.last_message_id = 0;
            if (user.user.messages.length > 0) {
                $scope.last_message_id = last_msg_id;
            }

           
                $scope.getMessages(user);    
           
           
          

            // $scope.last_msg = user.user.last_msg;
            // $scope.last_msg_type = user.user.last_msg_type;

            $('#third_img_div').show();
            $('#first_img_div').hide();
            $("#no-users-div").hide();
            
        }
        else
        {

            $('#third_img_div').hide();
            $('#first_img_div').show();
            $("#no-users-div").hide();

        }

     
    }

    $scope.loadChatDataFirst = function() {
        
        $scope.loadChatData($scope.chatUsers[0], 0);
    }



}); 



/* this is socket factory */
App.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  
  var socket = io(websocket_domain+":"+server_port);

  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {  
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  };
});

/* end of socket factory */
```

Comment: This is what I get in the console view /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lqd7b8k net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Comment: When I send message I can see $scope.messageInput hello but nothing gets sent to the chat windows

Comment: On the demo website I see you are connected
WebsocketChat_angular.js:995 $scope.messageInput hello
WebsocketChat_angular.js:5 anchor scroll fired

Comment: when there is too much code like that, please make a jsfiddle representating the issue. Also, try to define your problem more and explain what works and what not. Is your socket a problem only for sending ? Only reception ? Both ? If no one sends anything is there a bug ? And finally, if you forgot some precisions in your post, try to edit it instead of adding comments :)